# Can't set view params to WRAP_CONTENT programatically

Tags: android, view

I am trying to set a custom view to wrap_content in both height and width programatically. The problem is that no matter what i do it is always presented as match_parent.

This is the view

```
public class Circle extends View
{
public Circle(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(0xffff0000);
    canvas.drawCircle(mmToPx(4), mmToPx(4), mmToPx(4), paint);
}

public float mmToPx(int mm) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return mm * displayMetrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);
}
```

this is the main code

```
public void addCircle()
{
    Circle circle = new Circle(this);

    Random r = new Random();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams cParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);
    cParams.setMargins(r.nextInt((int) (w - (mmToPx(diam)))), r.nextInt((int) (h - (mmToPx(diam)))), 0, 0);
    circle.setLayoutParams(cParams);
    circle.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
    Log.v("sd", circle.getLayoutParams().width + "");
    circle.setId(R.id.circle);
    circle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++; scoreTv.setText("Score:\n"+count);
            frame.removeView(findViewById(R.id.circle));
            addCircle();
        }
    });
    frame.addView(circle);
}
```

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First-  NEVER use magic numbers like -2.  Use ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.  Otherwise your code becomes difficult to read and may contain bugs (for example, if they changed the value).

Second-  you aren't actually using cParams anywhere.  You want to use the version of addView that takes the view and the layout params.  Otherwise how will it know to use those layout params with that view.

Third-  you don't have an onMeasure function in your view.  Without that, how will it know how big your view is so it can actually wrap content on it?  You'll need to define onMeasure so it can get the width and height of your view.

Comment: 1. thanks for suggesting this, i have never thought of that.                                       2. setting circle to cParams - i am using it.                                                                                3. what should i define when overriding onMeasure?

Comment: for all who see this - i finally understood how it worked from this link http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> try this:
> ```

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
```